# Nhibernate CreateSQLQuery error - SetParameterList Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, nhibernate, sql-server-2012

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ','

Code:

```
IQuery permissionTypes;

if (regionIds != null && regionIds.Count > 0)
{
    permissionTypes =  session.CreateSQLQuery(
       @"SELECT DISTINCT PT.PermissionType FROM AspNetUsers AU 
       INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles AR ON AU.Id= AR.UserId
       INNER JOIN dbo.AspNetRoles ANR ON ANR.Id = AR.RoleId
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_RolePermissionTypeAssoc] RPT ON RPT.FK_RoleId  = AR.RoleId
       INNER JOIN tbl_PermissionType PT ON RPT.FK_permissionTypeId=PT.Id 
       WHERE AU.ID=:userId AND ANR.RegionId=:regionId")
       .SetParameter("userId", userId).SetParameterList("regionId", regionIds);
}
else
{
    permissionTypes =  session.CreateSQLQuery(
       @"SELECT DISTINCT PT.PermissionType FROM AspNetUsers AU 
       INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles AR ON AU.Id= AR.UserId
       INNER JOIN dbo.AspNetRoles ANR ON ANR.Id = AR.RoleId
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_RolePermissionTypeAssoc] RPT ON RPT.FK_RoleId  = AR.RoleId
       INNER JOIN tbl_PermissionType PT ON RPT.FK_permissionTypeId=PT.Id 
       WHERE AU.ID=:userId AND ANR.RegionId=:regionId")
       .SetParameter("userId", userId);
}

return permissionTypes.List<string>();
```

Generated query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PT.PermissionType 
FROM AspNetUsers AU 
INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles AR ON AU.Id = AR.UserId
INNER JOIN dbo.AspNetRoles ANR ON ANR.Id = AR.RoleId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_RolePermissionTypeAssoc] RPT ON RPT.FK_RoleId  = AR.RoleId
INNER JOIN tbl_PermissionType PT ON RPT.FK_permissionTypeId = PT.Id 
WHERE AU.ID = @p0 AND ANR.RegionId = @p1, @p2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is the **`=`** sign, it cannot be used for more arguments. We need **`IN`** operator

resluting sql contains

```
AND ANR.RegionId = @p1, @p2
```

and this coma is reported in the error. We need:

```
AND ANR.RegionId IN (@p1, @p2)
```

`if` part

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(
    @"SELECT DISTINCT PT.PermissionType FROM AspNetUsers AU 
    INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles AR ON AU.Id= AR.UserId
    INNER JOIN dbo.AspNetRoles ANR ON ANR.Id = AR.RoleId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_RolePermissionTypeAssoc] RPT 
            ON RPT.FK_RoleId  = AR.RoleId
    INNER JOIN tbl_PermissionType PT ON RPT.FK_permissionTypeId=PT.Id 
    // this is wrong 
    // WHERE AU.ID=:userId AND ANR.RegionId=:regionId 
    // we need IN 
    WHERE AU.ID=:userId AND ANR.RegionId IN (:regionId) 
    ")
    .SetParameter("userId", userId)
    .SetParameterList("regionId", regionIds);
```

And also in the else part we are using params which are not passed

`else` part:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(
   @"SELECT DISTINCT PT.PermissionType FROM AspNetUsers AU 
   INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles AR ON AU.Id= AR.UserId
   INNER JOIN dbo.AspNetRoles ANR ON ANR.Id = AR.RoleId
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_RolePermissionTypeAssoc] RPT ON RPT.FK_RoleId  = AR.RoleId
   INNER JOIN tbl_PermissionType PT ON RPT.FK_permissionTypeId=PT.Id

   -- here is again RegionId, but that is not passed
   WHERE AU.ID=:userId AND ANR.RegionId=:regionId")
   .SetParameter("userId", userId);
```

RegionId is expected again but not passed

Comment: Great to see that. Enjoy mighty NHibernate ;)